# Angular date range picker with range validation

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, daterangepicker

I write application for car booking. If somebody book car for some period, Im disabling this period on datepicker. But all date pickers that I test allows take period that contains disabled zones
[image: For example like here]

Anybody know datepicker that not alows take period with disabled zones? Or maybe you know other way how to do it

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I've used two Angular Material DatePickers, one for a *begin date* and one for an *end date*. In order to disable certain days, you can use the `matDatepickerFilter` for filter validation. See the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).

The Angular Material team is supposed to add range selection to the DatePicker in the first quarter of this year. See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4763) on their GitHub.